# laravel POST input not working

Tags: php, laravel

I'm really not sure why my controller is not receiving the attribute and value input! Here's my system.

View

```
<form method="POST" action="create/attribute">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="12u$">

      <input type="text" id="attribute" >
      <input type="text" id="value" >
    </div>

      <div class="12u$">
        <ul class="actions">
          <li><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="special" /></li>
          <li><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Controller

```
public function store()
    {
        dd(request()->all());
}
```

route

```
Route::post('/stimulus/create/attribute', 'Attributes@store');
```

When I press submit I receive

```
    array:1 [▼
  "_token" => "K4TSq9lVQq8etkH8lPDxfUJ8g9oF58wm2kJ2pwlz"
]
```

But nothing else. I'm really unsure what I'm missing here!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing the `name` attribute on both of the input element inside the `form`

```
   <input type="text" name="attribute" id="attribute" /> 
                       ^
   <input type="text" name ="value" id="value" />
                       ^
```

and then fix the `store` function inside `controller`

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{
    dd(request()->all());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I don't know why sometimes I forget this...